# Magento 2 Diffeent Product Page design for different Category

Tags: magento2, product

I need product pages design different for each category.I have around 5-6 categories.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make custom templates for different categories and specify it in  **Layout Update XML** field of the category on which you want it to be.

Comment: ,please let me know with example.